# problem creating an easy context free grammar that has some conditions

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need help with a CF grammar, that has to generate the following:

> {a<sup>n</sup> c b<sup>m</sup> | m>=n>=0}

That is the conclusion that i came up with:

```
S<sub>0</sub>->aAb | aSb

S<sub>1</sub>->Acb | ε
```

but It is not correct because it doesn't respect the conditions `m>=n>=0` and moreover It creates many c, when instead I just need only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a language like `{a^n c b^n | n >= 0}`, which will have a rule that consumes an `a` for every `b` and vice versa:

```
S -> A | ε
A -> aAb | c
```

Then make use of the fact that another way of saying `m >= n` is to say that `m = n + k | k >= 0`. So you can express your language as `{a^n c b^n b^k | n >= 0, k >= 0}`, which I'll leave as an exercise to you how to construct.